# There is a phantom colored shape at the bottom of my render, when rendering 360 VR

Tags: rendering, particles

I'm new to Blender, and I'm working on incorporating a basic snow flurry particle system into some pre-existing video. When rendering my scene I have a strange light blue object that appears at the bottom of my render. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to correct it?

```
   I have included my outliner to show that there is no visible object in the scene which might be rendering, and the viewport render showing that there is nothing under my camera.
```

[image: Outliner]

[image: Viewport]

[image: Render Output]

Comment: I cannot tell from the screenshot what it is, but the _Outliner_ clearly shows that the object "Sphere.001" is disabled in the viewport (the eye symbol) but it is still visible in render (the camera symbol).

Comment: Absolutely right - I feel like posting the Picard face palm.